# Spring Boot Enum display names to and from the View

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums

I want to convert my `Enum` snake case values to, and from human readable values in the view in my Spring Boot 3 project.

The environment is Spring Boot 3, MySQL 8 with the associated Jackson and Hibernate dependencies. I am working with React for the front end.

I have read Baedungs article [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-values), but I am none the wiser despite having implemented a "label" - it may also be that I am using DTO's with nested classes and perhaps this extra layer is causing confusion.

My setup:

**Bird Domain Class**

```
public class Bird {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Taxa taxa;
}
```

**Enum Taxa**

```
public enum Taxa {

    BROWN_BIRD("Brown Bird"),
    GREAT_BIRD("Great Bird"),
    SMALL("Small");

    private final String label;

    Taxa(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

And then used in the view I have a DTO class:

**BirdDTO**

```
public class BirdDto {
   public Long id;
   public String name;
   public Taxa taxa;
   ...
   public String getTaxa() { return taxa.getLabel(); }
}
```

I can get the display labels, but how can I use the display values from the react view to persist enums and ideally do it in a case-insensitive way to make the code more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the corresponding field with `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue` like this:

```
public enum Taxa {
    BROWN_BIRD("Brown Bird"),
    GREAT_BIRD("Great Bird"),
    SMALL("Small");

    
    private final String label;

    Taxa(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

The fitting Baeldung article is here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: Sorry I update the question the issue is persisting the ENUM's not getting them.

Comment: @JsonValue should still be the answer. However if you want to have case-insensitivity you need to have Taxa as a String and parse it by hand.

Comment: use `@JsonValue` on a setTaxa setter?

Comment: I think putting it on the field instead should work fine.